# excel formula multiple if criteria including date comparison

Tags: excel, formatting, formulas

In excel, I need to check if all of the below are true:

- Column G says "Void"
- Column J says "No"
- The date in column E is after 4/9/2014

If all are true, I need to highlight the cell in column L

**Formula:**
`=AND(FIND("Void",G2), FIND("No",J2),$E2>=DATEVALUE("4/10/2014"))`

- **I also tried:**
  `=AND(FIND("Void",G2), FIND("No",J2),$E2>=DATE(2014,4,10))`

**Applies to:**
`=$L$2:$L$5000`

I can get the above to work without the date check. After I put that part in, it no longer highlights the cell but no error is shown.

What do I need to change?

Comment: What is the value of `E2`? Is it a real date, or maybe a string that only looks like a date?

Comment: also you should use: `=AND(ISNUMBER(FIND("Void",G2)), ISNUMBER(FIND("No",J2)),..)`. And you can change `Find` to `Search` - only difference is that `Serach` case-insensitive

Comment: @chris neilson, I dont understand, what is `ISNUMBER` doing in this case exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure what I was doing wrong yesterday but I tried the same formula again today and now it works.